# Square root values are not display properly in mathjax plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ckeditor, mathjax

In my view page the square root values are not displaying properly. I'm using the mathjax plugin and ckeditor along with the following scripts in the top of my page like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof MathJax !== 'undefined') {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
  }
</script>
```